# Hide Authoring info on certain pages/nodes

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I am looking for a way to hide the "Submitted By: .... on ...." info on certain pages. I am aware that it can be removed from all pages of the 'Basic Page' or 'Article' type through the configuration settings, however I would like the info to appear on all pages unless I turn on a setting whilst creating/editing the page which hides it on that certain page.
Does anyone know of a way to do this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You could add a checkbox field to the content type, and adjust the node.tpl file. If the box is not checked, don't print submitted by.

Add the field to all content types (sounds like thats what you asked for) and remove it from each display under "Manage Display".

Then, in template.php, implement `template_preprocess_node`:

```
mythemename_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

  // here we are creating a brand new variable
  // true, unless otherwise set by editors
  $variables['show_authoring'] = TRUE;

  // the field exists on the node object
  // update our custom variable to this field value
  if (isset($node->field_show_authoring)) {
    $variables['show_authoring'] = $node->field_show_authoring[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  }
}
```

If you want all nodes have this, you can copy in node.tpl.php to your theme or edit the one in your theme if it exists, and do:

```
<?php if ($display_submitted && $show_authoring): ?>
  <div class="submitted">
    <?php print $submitted; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You could remove `$display_submitted` if you wanted to, I left that there in case you wanted control in the future to completely disable showing authoring for certain content types, like Webform for example. My syntax should be correct but I did not have a chance to test this in a sandbox.

See more:

- [template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7.x)
- [How do I create a variable for my template file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15539/how-do-i-create-a-variable-that-my-page-tpl-php-file-can-access)
- [Preprocessing function for node.tpl.php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72812/preprocess-function-for-node-tpl-php-file)

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You would add a Boolean field to the content type(s), then write some logic in the node.tpl file of your theme. If the value is FALSE, don't print submitted by. Editors can then check on or off show submitted by on a node by node basis.

Comment: Ok, I've set up the Boolean field (checkbox) on the content type. Now, what code would I use to control whether the Authoring info is shown depending on the value of the boolean? (Sorry, I have no clue when it comes to PHP)

Comment: Basically, you are 'hooking in' to the node preprocess function, and adding a variable. This variable holds the truth value of the checkbox field, and then we add to the conditional that displays the submitted information in the template.

Comment: Thank you @Kevin. I will try this when I get home and let you know how I get on.

Comment: So, what bits of text in there do I need to change to make it work with my code? I can see that I need to change 'mythemename' to the name of the theme I am using but is there anything else that I need to change to make it work?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I tried this and it worked, BUT it only works if the show authoring info is enabled for the content type. However, if that is enabled, then it shows to 'Submitted By's one from drupal, one from your code. Is there a way around this? Also, is there a way to make your code 'Submitted By' show BEFORE the body of the page rather than after? Cheers,

Comment: Right, each content type would need that field added. Sounded like you wanted it for all content types. The arrangement of the posted date can be done from the template. Did you make new fields or something for author and date? The submitted by information is at the top of the node by default per node.tpl.php.

Comment: I only created one field. Just a boolean checkbox to turn the submitted by info on or off.

Comment: In the core node.tpl.php, submitted by does not come after the page content. That is probably from the theme you are using? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7.x

Comment: No, it's not the theme. The submitted by does show above the body. It would only show below when 2 were showing. One above, one below. Also, I changed the code and remove `$display_submitted` so you only need the text box clicked to show submitted by. However now, I get a submitted box with nothing in it showing whether the box is checked or not.